# LIFO Stack that Pushes every Pop in SQL

Tags: sql, stack

Given an example table such as:

```
CREATE TABLE TESTING_Order(
    Order INT, 
    Name VARCHAR(5)
)

INSERT INTO TESTING_Order 
VALUES
    (0, 'Zero'),
    (1, 'One'),
    (2, 'Two'),
    (3, 'Three'),
    (4, 'Four'),
    (5, 'Five'),
    (6, 'Six'),
    (7, 'Seven')
```

I'd like to know how to implement a sort of 'Stack' to show, for instance, the turn order in a game where the first player moves 'left' each turn. I can accomplish this using two update statements:

```
UPDATE TESTING_Order
SET Order = Order + 1

UPDATE TESTING_Order 
SET Order = (SELECT Min(Order) -1 FROM TESTING_Order)
WHERE Order = (SELECT MAX(Order) FROM TESTING_Order)
```

I was wondering if there is a cleaner/more proper way of doing this, and especially if that other way can be done using a single UPDATE statement.

In other words, I think what I'm after is a better implementation of a LIFO Stack that performs a push on every pop--excuse me for possibly butchering any terminology.

Comment: Are you just looking for a modulus operator, like `... SET Order = (Order + 1) % (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table)`? (or `MAX() + 1` if you preferred that over `COUNT()` for some reason; either way, it appears to assume that the numbers are all consecutive with no gaps) Regardless, if you execute your multiple statements within a transaction, they'll effectively be executed as one atomic operation, if that's what you're worried about.

Comment: The modulus operator would work perfectly. Either solution is acceptable--and you're right, the assumption is made that the values will be consecutive. I'm not as concerned about it executing once vs. executing twice, I was more curious about finding a way that could do it. Thanks so much for your feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just so that there is an answer here:

To cycle through the list I've decided to use:

```
UPDATE TESTING_Order
SET nOrder = 
    Case 
        WHEN (nOrder - 1) < 0 THEN (SELECT Count(*) FROM TESTING_Order) - 1
        WHEN (nOrder - 1) >= 0 THEN (nOrder - 1) % (SELECT MAX(nOrder) + 1 FROM TESTING_Order)
    END
```

This allows me to move the list in the correct way (which I realize my answer probably did not) and has the benefit of doing what I requested in just one statement. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, [Wiseguy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/185544/wiseguy).